# diagonalizable linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization

I am having difficulties solving this problem.
$V$ is the vector space of all polynomials (of complex numbers) of max degree $n$. $T$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to $V$.

$$T(p)(x)=p'(x)+p(0)\cdot x^n$$
Prove that T is diagonalizable.

Many thanks.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What's its matrix?

Comment: I used the standard base to find the matrix that represents the linear transformation then I tried finding the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Have you tried solving the equation $\lambda P = P(0)X^n + P'$ (unknowns $P,\lambda$)

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the basis $\left\{P_k = \frac{X^k}{k!}\right\}_{0 \le k \le n}$ then the matrix of $T$ is a companion matrix indeed, $$T(P_k) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} n! P_n & \text{if $k=0$} \\ P_{k-1} & \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$ The  characteristic polynomial of this matrix is $\chi(X) = X^{n+1} - n!$ which has distinct roots so $T$ is diagonalizable

Comment: This should be $X^{n+1}$ (degree at most $n$ yields dimension $n+1$)

Comment: Yes I correct it.

Comment: Why does the polynomial have distinct roots?

Comment: I think because the roots pf $X^p - a$ are $\{a^{\frac1p},a^{\frac1p}\omega_p,\ldots, a^{\frac1p}\omega_p^{p-1}\}$, where $\omega_p = e^{\frac{2i\pi}{p}}$

Answer (score 0):

A general member of $V$ will have the form

$p(x) = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots+a_nx^n$

Then $p(0) = a_0$, so

$T(p)(x) = a_1 + 2a_2x + 3a_3x^2 + \dots + na_nx^{n-1}+a_0x^n$

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ then

$T(p)(x) = \lambda(x)$

so

$a_1 = \lambda a_0$

$2a_2 = \lambda a_1 = \lambda^2a_0$

$3a_3 = \lambda a_2 \Rightarrow 6a_3 = \lambda^3a_0$

and so on, until finally:

$n!a_n = \lambda^na_0$

$a_0 = \lambda a_n \Rightarrow n!a_0 = \lambda^{n+1}a_0$

So the eigenvalues $\lambda$ are the roots of the characteristic equation

$\lambda^{n+1} = n!$

which has $n+1$ distinct roots in the complex numbers. This is a sufficient condition for $T$ to be diagonalizable.

Comment: Not at all. You proved that $\text{Sp} (A) \subset \text{roots}(X^{n+1} - n!)$ but you did not prove the reciproque